# Database Join functionality implements in PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, database

what is the best way to realize the SQL-Join functionality in PHP.
I need that because I have to join "Tables" data (an Object or array of arrays, etc) from databases on different hosts.

Any Ideas better than looping over all rows?

Note: It' shouldn't be in PHP :)

Comment: Take a look (and possibly use) Doctrine, Propel or Eloquent (Eloquent's a part of Laravel framework). Googling about mentioned 3 should put you on the right path.

Comment: @N.B.: You're sure you're not just throwing phrases here? How do any of these support cross-datasource relationships?

Comment: I do not think that looping over all rows is a bad idea.

Comment: Doctorine, Propel or the other ROM-Mapper use the DatabaseManagmentSystem and dosen't support my scenario **distributed databases**

Comment: There are some ways to do it. It would be helpful, if you post some code. How do you store data and what exactly do you want to achieve. Basically if join condition id one-column, you can use it as array index and simply merge arrays.

Comment: By the way, you will loop over all rows, whether you want or not. If not explicit, then PHP function that you use will do that in it's native code.

Comment: I don't save the data local for the time.

Comment: I have adapter classes to get the data from the distributed data sources. And I'm looking for an algorithem or a data structure to support join (merge and filter) the data rows in php, because i cann't join the data of tow tables on tow different databse hosts :(

Answer (score 1):

Only a suggestion, if your key is the same, then create a multidimensional array with the key as your index. and then assign any data accordingly. like array[key][valuefromtable1]=array();
array[key][valuefromtable2]=array();

Comment: I had also the same idea :)